# Can Cocos2D-JS encrypt the source code?

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

1. If I'm using Cocos2D-JS to make a HTML 5 game, can I encrypt the JavaScript source code, so that no one can use it?
2. If encrypting doesn't work, the only way is to obfuscate the JavaScript. If I use Cocos2D-JS to make an Android/IOS app, is it possible for a hacker to get my source code?

Comment: The deal is you are using a language that can be seen presumably because of it's ease of use. The tradeoff is anyone else can see the code as well. So some may use the code without authorization but that does not mean all is lost, the majority will just use the app. Some lose is unavoidable  but that des not mean the method (JS) can't be used or that the app will be unsuccessful.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is an [interpreted language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language). In general, this means that a client must be able to read the code to execute it. This is a deliberate, fundamental feature of JavaScript's design, and is [advantageous in many respects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language#Advantages_of_interpreting_a_language).

That being said, there have been recent efforts to create an intermediate bytecode-style language that JavaScript can be compiled to (for example, [asm.js](http://asmjs.org/)). The aim of projects like asm.js, however, is not obfuscation but speed of execution (with particular regards to video games), so you cannot rely on their use to make your code un-readable.

There are many tools available that *minify* JavaScript code, making the code not-easily human readable (for example, by removing all whitespace and renaming variables to single-letters). Popular examples of these tools are [closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/#what-is-the-closure-compiler) and [uglify js](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS). It will always be possible to *un-minify* the code generated by these tools, however.

The *minification* of your JavaScript code is a **recommended** practice, however, because it makes your source files many times smaller and therefore the load time of your application is reduced significantly (less data to send over the network).

I am also aware of tools that claim to be JavaScript *obfuscators*, like [this one](http://www.danstools.com/javascript-obfuscate/). *obfuscators* use cheap tricks to make the code less readable (like abusing the `eval` method and changing character encodings). The results of these tools, however, like minification, can always be un-done. Please be aware that the use of these tools, unlike minification, will increase the size of the code **significantly** and may cause your code to run **much more** slowly.

> In a nutshell, **no, it is not possible** to "encrypt" or "obfuscate" your JavaScript code so that it is impossible for anybody to copy it.

The very nature of the internet is that anybody can obtain a copy of your program easily. If you are looking to protect your source code, a JavaScript program served over the internet is probably not the best distribution platform to use.

As a side-note, you may want to look into the benefits of **open-sourcing** your software and releasing it under a free license like the GNU GPL or the MIT. This means deliberately giving away your source code for free, and it can give developers who find your software useful the opportunity to improve it and help your users out.